# Zener diode on NRST pin of STM32

Tags: power-supply, circuit-design, stm32, zener, nrst

I am using STM32L476QGI6 in my project. As shown in the following figure, I have placed a 3.6 V Zener diode (ZM4729A-GS08) on the NRST pin of my microcontroller.

The problem is that when I connect the 3.3 V power supply to the MCU, sometimes the microcontroller turns on, and sometimes it does not!

When I remove the Zener diode, the circuit and MCU work perfectly. I don't understand the effect of the Zener diode on the circuit's functioning.
Previously, in another project, I used the same circuit for the NRST of the MCU, and the MCU was an STM32F103RDT6, where the same problem was observed.

[image: Schematic of the NRST circuit]

[Edit] The MCU_NRST node is also connected to a connector used for programming the MCU using ST-Link. Therefore, I used the Zener diode for ESD protection. I also employed it to prevent high-voltage damage to the programmer or PC, which could potentially affect the signal circuit of my board.

Comment: Why do you even have a zener there, what is the purpose, and have you measured the NRST pin voltage with multimeter or observed the waveform with an oscilloscope, to find out what is the difference and why it does not work? Also why do you have a pull-up on NRST pin?

Comment: Do you have anything else connected to node MCU_NRST? It looks like you've named that node for something somewhere else to sense or control.

Comment: What is this zener diode used for? It should be TVS diode instead, I think. TVS diodes connected in this way are used for ESD protection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The zener, if made by Vishay, has 3.6V voltage with +/- 5% tolerance.

The problem is the rated current, where the voltage is 3.6V +/- 5%, is 69mA.

And zener diodes are not ideal devices. They start conducting current far before the zener voltage. And these low voltage zeners do not have very sharp knee like higher voltage zeners do.

Unfortunately, the Vishay data sheets do not have graphs of voltage vs current.

The expectation is, the zener prevents the MCU from coming out of reset, the voltage may just be very close at the threshold of MCU being held in reset or allowed to run.

Comment: The STM32 datasheet says that the threshold on NRST is \$0.7V_{DD}=2.3V\$, and that leaves only a volt across R237, for 100μA of current. I looked up a few 3.6V zener diode curves and was shocked to see that many of them require 2mA to develop 2.3V! Good call!

Comment: @SimonFitch The R237 also should not be in the circuit. Recommendations of putting it in in noisy environments was removed years ago.